# Wordpress site not reading select tag

Tags: html, wordpress

Im having trouble with this wordpress site.

http://t4.rd-client.com/magicjack/information/area-codes-exchanges/

I have a select box in the code as shown here.

```
<select name="country" id="country">
    <option value="">Something</option>
    <option value="">Something</option>
    <option value="">Something</option>
</select>
```

Here is a screenshot of the code
[image: https://gyazo.com/d1c476547faaf2f31e7c1a95ee5f71ef]

For some reason, the page is loading like this.
[image: https://gyazo.com/9886562f5d5bfda16e7443381f4f8f97]

you can see in the developer tools that the browser is rendering p tags. Not sure why this is happening.

I am using Wordpress version 4.3.1 and on an updated chrome browser.

Comment: Have you tried disabling all of your plugins to see if it's a conflict from that?

Comment: Just deactivated all of the plugins and it is still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can read here https://en.support.wordpress.com/code/, the select tag is not allowed for security reasons.

What you could do is create a shortcode which you can read all about here https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API.

You could create something like:

```
[select type="open"]
    [option value=x]
    [...]
[select type="close"]

add_shortcode('select', 'shortcodeSelect');
    function shortcodeSelect($atts) {
    if ($atts['type'] === 'open') {
        return '<select>';
    }
    return '</select>';
}

add_shortcode('option', 'shortcodeOption');
function shortcodeOption($atts) {
    $value = isset($atts['value']) ? $atts['value'] : '';
    return '<option value="' . $value . '">' . $value . '</option>
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: I found out what it was. It was a theme setting to not allow certain tags. Not sure why it exists, but it was there :D